# Product of infinite Fort's spaces is a normal space

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Let $X$ be an infinite Fort space with accumulation point $x_0$, and $Y$ be an infinite Fort space with accumulation point $y_0$. Prove that topological product $X\times Y$ is a normal space ($T_1$+$T_4$ space).

This can be proved using the fact that arbitrary Fort space is compact, together with the fact that a product of compact spaces is compact and therefore a normal space. However, I want to prove this claim without using the notion of compactness. I found proof of this type in Engelking General topology (example 2.3.36.):

"The Cartesian product $X\times Y$ is a normal space. This follows from the fact that for every pair of disjoint closed subsets of $X\times Y$ there exists an open and closed set $V\times W\subset X\times Y$ containing $(x_0,y_0)$ and disjoint from at least one of the closed sets, and **from the normality of the subspace $X\times Y\setminus(V\times W)$, which in its turn follows from 2.2.4 and 2.2.7.**"

Proposition 2.2.4 and Theorem 2.2.7 are related to the topological sums. Proposition 2.2.4. claims that every space that can be decomposed as a union of pairwise disjoint open subsets is a topological sum of these subspaces. Theorem 2.2.7 claims that a topological sum of $T_i$ spaces is a $T_i$ space, for $i\leqslant6$.

I understand the first part of the proof: If $G,H$ are disjoint, closed subsets of $X\times Y$, then at least one of them does not contain $(x_0,y_0)$; let say $(x_0,y_0)\notin G$. Then $(X\times Y)\setminus G$ is open set containing $(x_0,y_0)$, so we can choose open sets $V\subset X$ and $W\subset Y$ such that $(x_0,y_0)\in V\times W\subset (X\times Y)\setminus G$. Clearly that $V\times W$ is also a closed set, because $X\setminus V$ and $Y\setminus W$ are finite sets and $(X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)=((X\setminus V)\times Y)\cup(X\times(Y\setminus W))$.

I don't understand the marked part of the proof. How we are going to prove the normality of the subspace $(X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)$ from 2.2.4 and 2.2.7 and how we are going to use this fact to prove the normality of the $X\times Y$, especially in the case when $(x_0,y_0)\in H$?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found the proof:

**(a) Proof that $(X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)$ is a normal subspace of product $X\times Y$**

We concluded that sets $X\setminus V$ and $Y\setminus W$ are finite; we may assume that $X\setminus V=\{x_1,\dotsc,x_m\}$ and $Y\setminus W=\{y_1,\dotsc,y_n\}$. The set $(X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)$ can be decomposed as a topological sum of open subspaces
$(X\setminus V)\times (Y\setminus W)$, $V\times(Y\setminus W)$ and $(X\setminus V)\times W$.
Also, we have
$V\times(Y\setminus W)=\displaystyle\bigcup_{j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}} V\times\{y_j\}$ and $(X\setminus V)\times W=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in\{1,\dotsc,m\}} \{x_i\}\times W$. $(X\setminus V)\times (Y\setminus W)$ is a discrete subspace and therefore a normal subspace. For each $i\in\{1,\dotsc,m\}$, subspace $\{x_i\}\times W$ is also normal, since it is homeomorphic to the closed subspace $W$ of the normal space $Y$. Similarly, for each $j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, subspace $V\times\{y_j\}$ is normal, since it is homeomorphic to the closed subspace $V$ of the normal space $X$. This means that $(X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)$ is a normal subspace as a topological sum of a normal subspaces.

**(b) Proof that $X\times Y$ is a normal space**

We distinguish two cases:

$(i) H\cap \big((X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)\big)=\emptyset$

In this case, $H\subseteq V\times W$ and $G\subseteq(X\setminus V)\times (Y\setminus W)$.

$(ii) H\cap \big((X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)\big)\ne\emptyset$

In this case, $G$ and  $H\cap \big((X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)\big)$ as a disjoint closed sets of the normal subspace $(X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)$ can be separated by a disjoint open sets $V'$ and $W'$ of this subspace, such that $G\subseteq V'$ and $H\cap \big((X\times Y)\setminus(V\times W)\big)\subseteq W'$. Then $G\subseteq V'$ and $H\subseteq W'\cup(V\times W)$, which means that $V'$ and $W'\cup(V\times W)$ are the disjoint open sets we are looking for.

Thus,  $X\times Y$ is a normal space.